# how to build CPP project in TFS 2012 update 1 build

Tags: c++, build, tfs

i am trying to compile a cpp project on in my auto build and i get this messages

The imported project "c:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found.

i add the reg key for the location

and got this message

The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props

of course i saw this post but i want to solve it without install visual studio on my build machine

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c22511b-3117-40e6-846b-81042bd30507/tfs2010-build-machine-can-not-build-cpp-project

help would be appreciate

thanks shlomi

Comment: Are you asking how to build C++ on a machine which doesn't have a compiler installed?

Comment: yes i want to build it on my tfs build machine without install visual studio like i do when i build c# project

Answer (score 0):

Install a Windows SDK (e.g. [7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)) to get a build environment similar to Visual Studio. You need to select one that supports the MSVC toolset you are using (v110). I believe 7.1 does.